# How to do the jiggling effect on a Bitmap using opengl-es in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to make an application like `Magic Butt` application [Youtube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gz2hgEdGuqQ&has_verified=1)

It has a jiggling jelly like effect on a 2D image Bitmap when a user touches it. As far as I can figure out, this can be done by modifying the mesh on which this bitmap is attached using openGL, but I don't know how to display that stretching effect.

Is there an open source library to do this for me in Android?

I don't know how to go forward about it. Please throw some pointers.